# Typescript and Context API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to implement Typescript and Context API together in an application. I am facing the issue of implementing the function of deleteMovie and addMovie into the MovieContext.Provider's value prop.

Here's the error that I'm receiving:

```
Type '{ movies: MovieAttribute[]; deleteMovie: (id: number) => void; addMovie: (id: number, title: string) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ movies: { id: number; title: string; }[]; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'deleteMovie' does not exist in type '{ movies: { id: number; title: string; }[]; }'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(337, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ movies: { id: number; title: string; }[]; }>'
```

From what I understand from the error, am I correct to say that I have yet to declare that my Provider's value did not include a 'function type'. If so, how can I amend this issue?

MovieContext.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import MovieReducer from '../reducers/MovieReducer';

const initialState = { 
    movies: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "King Kong"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Spiderman"
        }
    ]
};

export const MovieContext = createContext(initialState);

export const MovieProvider = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(MovieReducer, initialState);

    // Actions
    function deleteMovie(id: number): void {
        dispatch({
            type: 'DELETE_MOVIE',
            payload: { id, title: 'nil' }
        })
    }

    function addMovie(id: number, title: string): void {
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_MOVIE',
            payload: { id, title }
        })
    }

    return (
        <MovieContext.Provider value={{
            movies: state.movies,
            deleteMovie,
            addMovie
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </MovieContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Do let me know if any part of the code can be improve as well! I just started working on Typescript recently and Context just literally today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the context is determined on it's declaration. You need to specify the type when calling `createContext` along with reasonable defaults if the context is retrieved without a context provider in the tree above:

```
// You could move the anonymous type between <> to an interface 
export const MovieContext = createContext<{
  movies: Movie[],
  deleteMovie(id: number): void;
  addMovie(id: number, title: string): void;
}>({
  ...initialState,
  addMovie: () => {},
  deleteMovie: () => {}
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDec1SoxIDCEAdsQB5ZwCuAzksgCZ1pJRwC+cAZlAgg4AckLoYIgNwAoGWgoN4wcsBjAUAGwDKMFMTgBeXHBlxzcEBABuwJAwBccANpmL7nG-fe4wFk4BGTC8fC3UYTSQnACIAaRUAczhYigTokPduYNDcDNC-JwAmbJywtUiY7TA-ThAUcnSc7hCAXRluWRgATzAkOABZGzsjOG7eiD5fVXUtXX0kZxErW3sRFudyOhAAI04W2RkAekO4AE0IOnwLzRZLGz6YAAs++oouq0ZRnr7dmAB3JBIchwAA8AD5RhA4PUpsQoHx0H0ZEgqJBYFdyEoBkNSBRqPBjAQiLjKCiYCDPOZlnZHNiVs4WiUWEhIsRBisABQFOCbHacACUTmsED8snMKBYLHZdi5-h5W12UGw4QqcCUUESgrgwtF7TBHMpcAAdCaVGoNDo9MQShKpTinBz+UYITgsm5maykNKonBHc7cM1uPyDnw6OQMMAKHS7Kx2JwOUp5k4xkgJlNzbMrUhsBJI+QnHg3CmnCIACIAUQAMuWACrlgD6-QA8gA1ACS5ZEcAAPqIAIKl0uN1sdkTYNxgFBdTQQCUF3xy3mK5XlH3qxI8dpwJ2GwgwOhQYGJ4iyZrI1HQeAKTHwb0ABUEtmZXGMHLAgjAtLwaEewBuhHzRBUAwI1kAkAA5CBmR4J1DBdEJryxZxj2zOAWGABhJxgH8WhGRhmCQNgOCgDlvVjYjsDNGZLXmYM5HcY44D7CNFBCUNw3UKMPSQNkcVlJwlwFIURVuQ0fHQzD9B-A08h8YtRAras62HdtOxKUo4EnadZzlPA-BXCIfREVRNC7Zomn5EIz3cdiWOBW1vX4+U+SVUZVycddyASLUdVE2S0IwrDpLE0p5JEAch2bVSx389wtJnOcTH0tzDM3CyrPoiw9wPYEOX8kFvTIUkaCNB8hmfbUtDoJBDBwEKcmpewPKzI1GoYdTSm43iVg6nIHJxfzuG4MFYosHB3wgT8jR-P8WAA8zQhBQ5CrxMlSsfGooBG9xLO4IA)

Comment: Thank you. Can I clarify that `addMovie: () => {}` is declaring that addMovie is a function? If so, are there any other way to declare a function in typescript?

Comment: @MongChangHsi it's just an empty function, you could also use `addMovie() {}`. This empty function should never actually be invoked as the default value of the context is never used if you have a `MovieContext.Provider` as a parent. Alternate values for `addMovies` would be `null!` (forcing null in something that should not be null) or `addMovie: () => { throw new Error("No context for movies exists")}`.  If you forget to add a provider  both these would result in runtime errors (which is actually probably a good thing). The empty function above would just silently not do anything.